# Cannot run spark v2.0.0 example on cluster

Tags: apache-spark, port, bind

So I have set up a Spark cluster. But I can't actually get it to work. When I submit the SparkPi example with:

```
./bin/spark-submit   --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi  \
  --master spark://x.y.129.163:7077  \
  --deploy-mode cluster   \
  --supervise  \
  --executor-memory 20G \
  --total-executor-cores 2  \
  examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.0.0.jar   1000
```

I get the following from the worker logs:

```
Spark Command: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.111-2.6.7.2.el7_2.x86_64/jre/bin/java -cp /opt/spark/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/conf/:/opt/spark/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/* -Xmx1g -XX:MaxPermSize=256m org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker --webui-port 8081 spark://mesos-master:7077
========================================
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
16/09/18 09:20:56 INFO Worker: Started daemon with process name: 23949@mesos-slave-4.novalocal
16/09/18 09:20:56 INFO SignalUtils: Registered signal handler for TERM
16/09/18 09:20:56 INFO SignalUtils: Registered signal handler for HUP
16/09/18 09:20:56 INFO SignalUtils: Registered signal handler for INT
16/09/18 09:20:56 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
16/09/18 09:20:56 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: root
16/09/18 09:20:56 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: root
16/09/18 09:20:56 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to:
16/09/18 09:20:56 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to:
16/09/18 09:20:56 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(root); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(root); groups with modify permissions: Set()
16/09/18 09:21:00 WARN ThreadLocalRandom: Failed to generate a seed from SecureRandom within 3 seconds. Not enough entrophy?
16/09/18 09:21:00 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkWorker' on port 55256.
16/09/18 09:21:00 INFO Worker: Starting Spark worker x.y.129.162:55256 with 4 cores, 6.6 GB RAM
16/09/18 09:21:00 INFO Worker: Running Spark version 2.0.0
16/09/18 09:21:00 INFO Worker: Spark home: /opt/spark/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7
16/09/18 09:21:00 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'WorkerUI' on port 8081.
16/09/18 09:21:00 INFO WorkerWebUI: Bound WorkerWebUI to x.y.129.162, and started at http://x.y.129.162:8081
16/09/18 09:21:00 INFO Worker: Connecting to master mesos-master:7077...
16/09/18 09:21:00 INFO TransportClientFactory: Successfully created connection to mesos-master/x.y.129.163:7077 after 33 ms (0 ms spent in bootstraps)
16/09/18 09:21:00 INFO Worker: Successfully registered with master spark://x.y.129.163:7077
16/09/18 09:21:00 INFO Worker: Asked to launch driver driver-20160918090435-0001
16/09/18 09:21:01 INFO DriverRunner: Launch Command: "/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.111-2.6.7.2.el7_2.x86_64/jre/bin/java" "-cp" "/opt/spark/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/conf/:/opt/spark/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/*" "-Xmx1024M" "-Dspark.executor.memory=20G" "-Dspark.submit.deployMode=cluster" "-Dspark.app.name=org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi" "-Dspark.cores.max=2" "-Dspark.rpc.askTimeout=10" "-Dspark.driver.supervise=true" "-Dspark.jars=file:/opt/spark/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.0.0.jar" "-Dspark.master=spark://x.y.129.163:7077" "-XX:MaxPermSize=256m" "org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.DriverWrapper" "spark://Worker@x.y.129.162:55256" "/opt/spark/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/work/driver-20160918090435-0001/spark-examples_2.11-2.0.0.jar" "org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi" "1000"
16/09/18 09:21:06 INFO DriverRunner: Command exited with status 1, re-launching after 1 s.
16/09/18 09:21:07 INFO DriverRunner: Launch Command: "/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.111-2.6.7.2.el7_2.x86_64/jre/bin/java" "-cp" "/opt/spark/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/conf/:/opt/spark/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/*" "-Xmx1024M" "-Dspark.executor.memory=20G" "-Dspark.submit.deployMode=cluster" "-Dspark.app.name=org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi" "-Dspark.cores.max=2" "-Dspark.rpc.askTimeout=10" "-Dspark.driver.supervise=true" "-Dspark.jars=file:/opt/spark/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.0.0.jar" "-Dspark.master=spark://x.y.129.163:7077" "-XX:MaxPermSize=256m" "org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.DriverWrapper" "spark://Worker@x.y.129.162:55256" "/opt/spark/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/work/driver-20160918090435-0001/spark-examples_2.11-2.0.0.jar" "org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi" "1000"
16/09/18 09:21:12 INFO DriverRunner: Command exited with status 1, re-launching after 1 s.
```

i.e. the job/driver appears to be failing and then retrying indefinitely.

When I look at the starter from the driver on the worker node I see:

```
Launch Command: "/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.111-2.6.7.2.el7_2.x86_64/jre/bin/java" "-cp" "/opt/spark/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/conf/:/opt/spark/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/*" "-Xmx1024M" "-Dspark.executor.memory=20G" "-Dspark.submit.deployMode=cluster" "-Dspark.app.name=org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi" "-Dspark.cores.max=2" "-Dspark.rpc.askTimeout=10" "-Dspark.driver.supervise=true" "-Dspark.jars=file:/opt/spark/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.0.0.jar" "-Dspark.master=spark://x.y.129.163:7077" "-XX:MaxPermSize=256m" "org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.DriverWrapper" "spark://Worker@x.y.129.162:33364" "/opt/spark/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/work/driver-20160918090435-0001/spark-examples_2.11-2.0.0.jar" "org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi" "1000"
========================================

log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MutableMetricsFactory).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
16/09/18 09:13:18 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: root
16/09/18 09:13:18 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: root
16/09/18 09:13:18 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to: 
16/09/18 09:13:18 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to: 
16/09/18 09:13:18 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(root); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(root); groups with modify permissions: Set()
16/09/18 09:13:21 WARN ThreadLocalRandom: Failed to generate a seed from SecureRandom within 3 seconds. Not enough entrophy?
16/09/18 09:13:22 WARN Utils: Service 'Driver' could not bind on port 0. Attempting port 1.
16/09/18 09:13:22 WARN Utils: Service 'Driver' could not bind on port 0. Attempting port 1.
16/09/18 09:13:22 WARN Utils: Service 'Driver' could not bind on port 0. Attempting port 1.
16/09/18 09:13:22 WARN Utils: Service 'Driver' could not bind on port 0. Attempting port 1.
16/09/18 09:13:22 WARN Utils: Service 'Driver' could not bind on port 0. Attempting port 1.
16/09/18 09:13:22 WARN Utils: Service 'Driver' could not bind on port 0. Attempting port 1.
16/09/18 09:13:22 WARN Utils: Service 'Driver' could not bind on port 0. Attempting port 1.
16/09/18 09:13:22 WARN Utils: Service 'Driver' could not bind on port 0. Attempting port 1.
16/09/18 09:13:22 WARN Utils: Service 'Driver' could not bind on port 0. Attempting port 1.
16/09/18 09:13:22 WARN Utils: Service 'Driver' could not bind on port 0. Attempting port 1.
16/09/18 09:13:22 WARN Utils: Service 'Driver' could not bind on port 0. Attempting port 1.
16/09/18 09:13:22 WARN Utils: Service 'Driver' could not bind on port 0. Attempting port 1.
16/09/18 09:13:22 WARN Utils: Service 'Driver' could not bind on port 0. Attempting port 1.
16/09/18 09:13:22 WARN Utils: Service 'Driver' could not bind on port 0. Attempting port 1.
16/09/18 09:13:22 WARN Utils: Service 'Driver' could not bind on port 0. Attempting port 1.
16/09/18 09:13:22 WARN Utils: Service 'Driver' could not bind on port 0. Attempting port 1.
Exception in thread "main" java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: Service 'Driver' failed after 16 retries! Consider explicitly setting the appropriate port for the service 'Driver' (for example spark.ui.port for SparkUI) to an available port or increasing spark.port.maxRetries.
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:463)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:455)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel.doBind(NioServerSocketChannel.java:125)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.bind(AbstractChannel.java:485)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1089)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeBind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:430)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.bind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:415)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:903)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.bind(AbstractChannel.java:198)
    at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap$2.run(AbstractBootstrap.java:348)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:357)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

(excuse the timestamps, the logs are the same later on)

On the master I have:

```
# /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4 mesos-master
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6

x.y.129.155 mesos-slave-1
x.y.129.161 mesos-slave-2
x.y.129.160 mesos-slave-3
x.y.129.162 mesos-slave-4

# conf/spark-env.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
SPARK_MASTER_HOST=x.y.129.163
SPARK_LOCAL_IP=x.y.129.163
```

And for the worker I have:

```
# /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4 mesos-slave-4 mesos-slave-4.novalocal
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6

x.y.129.163 mesos-master

# conf/spark-env.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
SPARK_MASTER_HOST=x.y.129.163
SPARK_LOCAL_IP=x.y.129.162
```

I also disabled all ipv6 from `/etc/sysctl.conf`.

All daemons are started with the `sbin/start-master.sh` and `sbin/start-slave.sh spark://x.y.129.163:7077` commands.

Update: so I attempted the `spark-submit` again, but without the `--deploy-mode cluster`.... and it works! Any idea why it doesn't with cluster mode?

Comment: @zero323; even tho the machines are called mesos, my intent was to get spark running by itself first. so mesos, at this stage is not involved.

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue.  If you've been able to resolve it I'd love to hear what fix it for you.